# JavaScript regexp global option not working (as I) expect

Tags: javascript, regex

Consider

```
a = '<img src="one.png" alt="One"> <img src="two.png" alt="Two">' + "\n" + 
    '<img src="thr.png" alt="Thr"> <img src="fou.png" alt="Fou">'
i = '/a/b/c/d/blah'
b = a.replace(/<img src="(.*)"(.*)>/g, '<img src="' + i + '/$1"$2>')
```

Results in

```
'<img src="/a/b/c/d/blah/one.png" alt="One"> <img src="two.png" alt="Two">\n<img src="/a/b/c/d/blah/thr.png" alt="Thr"> <img src="fou.png" alt="Fou">'
```

Given the `/g` option, I was really expecting (and want) all instances of four instances of `src` to be prefixed with the value of `i`. What is my mistake?

Comment: Make the quantifiers non-greedy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `.*` is greedy, so it continues until it finds the last occurrence of what is next to it.
If you add `?`, it would not be greedy.
So -

`/<img src="(.*?)"(.*?)>/g`

Or you can be more specific (any character which is not `"` and later, any character which is not `>`) -

`/<img src="([^"]*)"([^>]*)>/g`

(Or both)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
a = '<img src="one.png" alt="One"> <img src="two.png" alt="Two">' + "\n" + 
    '<img src="thr.png" alt="Thr"> <img src="fou.png" alt="Fou">'
i = '/a/b/c/d/blah'
b = a.replace(/<img src="(.*?)"(.*?)>/g, '<img src="' + i + '/$1"$2>');
```

***EXPLANATION:***

```
Match the characters “<img src="” literally «<img src="»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “"” literally «"»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “>” literally «>»
```